# How to display HTML content in columns, horizontally scrollable?

Tags: css, html, scroll, internet-explorer-11

I have a list of simple HTML elements like divs, Paragraphs, etc. I'd like to display them in fixed height container, with the content shown in columns with same fixed width, all horizontally scrollable, just like it's [shown on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcA7.jpg).
The browser it should work in is IE11.
Any idea, how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Ie11 is a need, about fluid design you never heard? Uhhh...

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in:
`<div class="sample"></div>` and wrap them in a `<div class="container"></div>`

Give all `.sample` classes and `.container` a fixed width and height.

```
.sample {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
}
.container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3 columns
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

```
<div id="main">
    Content here, no wrapping divs needed...
</div>
```

Or even better using html5

```
<main>
     Content here, no wrapping divs needed...
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put all the elements in a container, and give it a width large enough to not wrap the elements around. The elements should either `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

Then put a div pane around, which shows a cutout of the container and give that pane `overflow-x: auto` in order to show a scrollbar when necessary

```html
<div class="pane">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</div>
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</div>
        <p class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.container {
    width: 1250px;
    max-height: 350px;
}
.container .column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubZpf/)